# Autobahn Python Errno 99 cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets, autobahn

While trying to set up a Websocket server, I have encountered the following error.
The same code works fine under LAN IP '192.168.x.x', but fails to work with a public ip/domain name

Here is the error trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WSServer.py", line 19, in <module>
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 208, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 243, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 319, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in create_server
    % (sa, err.strerror.lower()))
OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('121.6.x.x', 9000): cannot assign requested address
```

Python Server Code:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print("message received")
        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import asyncio
    from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory
    factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(factory, '121.6.x.x', 9000)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.close()
```

Could the issue be related with the server setting? e.g. hostname, SELinux

Comment: If you're behind a router, then your local IP is the `'192.18.x.x` address. You can't bind to the public address because that isn't actually a valid IP for your system. Instead you bind to the LAN IP, and use port forwarding on the router itself to forward requests sent to the public IP on to your system.

Comment: @dano, thank you. I have managed to get it to work. =)